# Is New York's formula for taxing non-residents constitutional? How?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york

When a New York State non-resident has NYS income, NY's tax rates are based NOT on the absolute amount of the NYS income, but on the non-resident's **federal** income, pro-rated to the percentage earned in NY.

For example, if the non-resident earns $5000 in NY, and $95,000 elsewhere, her tax is not based on a $5000 income, but rather, on 5% of a $100,000 income.   In this example 5% is the percent earned in NY.  The computation is on NY's form IT203, lines 31 to 46.

My question: How can a state compel a non-resident to even report income that was earned elsewhere, and then to levy taxes that are partly based on it?

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com or https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Those would both be appropriate venues, and it did occur to me.   But I think this one may be more appropriate.    At least, it's not obvious.  Can we give it a chance?  I'll be happy to move it if it gains no traction.

Comment: Can you explain the issue? 5% of 100k is 5k.

Comment: If it wasn't like this, you could earn a small amount in every single state and owe no state income tax anywhere. I can't speak to the constitutionality but it seems logical to me.

Comment: @HartCO I think they meant to say 5% of the tax on $100,000 income, rather than the tax on $5000 income.

Comment: Which part of the constitution do you think this practice is breaking?

Comment: @jay613 This would be an appropriate venue for a question like "how do I calculate how much tax I owe to New York?", but your question is more focused on the legal aspect than the financial.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica my inclination would be that it breaks the 5th amendment and 14th amendment. But solidified by the 16th amendment. The argument would be more about the differences in tax treatment than the ability to tax at all.

Comment: @jay613 My thought is that, logically, it must be considered constitutional, because if it wasn’t, it would have been challenged and struck down long ago. But I’m not a constitutional lawyer, nor is anyone on this site. Try law.SE. If you do, please post a link to the question here, because I’m curious.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I will.  A little help in framing the question, in the context of the pretty good answer below, would also be appreciated.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica In modern usage "This isn't constitutional" just means "I don't think it's fair".

Comment: There are double-tax agreements between countries such as [USA and Australia](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/aus.pdf). Perhaps intra-state agreements also exist in the USA.

Comment: I assume NYS has a progressive tax rate; this seems like a way assure the tax paid is as if the $5000 is taxed at the rate of a 100K earner, not a 5K earner, but is only paid on the $5000 subject to NYS taxation.   To the legality of a state seeing your federal income tax numbers, "Internal Revenue Code (IRC) Section 6103 authorizes the IRS to share tax information by entering into agreements with governmental agencies for tax administration purposes" https://www.irs.gov/government-entities/governmental-liaisons/irs-information-sharing-programs

Comment: @DJClayworth you're right and I'm guilty.  Sometimes an idea needs to be developed into a good question. Rather than "is this constitutional" the question I'm working on (for Law SE) is about what limits exist (if any) for states and towns to aggressively tax people outside their jurisdiction.  If NYS can do exactly what they do, on the basis that it is "progressive", and there are no legal boundaries, why hasn't any state in 200 years been far more aggressive?  Why isn't NYS more aggressive?  (Actually, they are, but that's a whole other question).  Etc.

Comment: New question asked in Law SE https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/64540/are-there-legal-or-constitutional-limits-to-us-states-taxing-non-resident-non-st. @BenMiller-RememberMonica

Comment: California taxes nonresidents in this way too. And if you think about it, this way of taxation makes the most sense. Consider Person A who makes $100k in one state, vs. Person B who makes $10k each in 10 states, all of which have the the same tax brackets. They both make the same amount total, so they should be taxed the same, but due to the progressive tax brackets, tax on $100k is much more than 10 times the tax on $10k. So if each state taxed nonresidents as if income from that state is all their income, Person B would pay less tax than Person A, which is not fair.

Comment: @user102008 I understand the objective of what NY and CA are doing, I just wonder how far it could go especially if the motivation was not benevolent.

Comment: I think @ChrisW.Rea had it right, 5 seconds after I posted this.  The answer may be on the border between law and politics.  States may be limited by what is economically and politically acceptable to its voters.  If a state oversteps, non-residents will cease to contribute to its economy and voters will respond accordingly.    Or perhaps overly aggressive approaches to taxing out of state income would encroach on the right of Congress to regulate Commerce (but the existing NY and CA approaches do not actually do so).  For now, the question is open in Law.

Comment: @DJClayworth This is a due-process question, so the modern usage is roughly correct. Not fair = not constitutional. See the answer on Law.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it sounds like NY is one of the states that plays nice.

Imagine that you had a warehouse in a state and no income was earned in that state.  Also, imagine that all your sales were in an adjacent state.  Imagine the state you sold in had no income tax.  Is none of your income taxable in the state with storage?

If the storage didn't exist, then sales would be reduced down to what could be held in the store.  The out of state storage materially impacts the income earned in the other state.  That additional income, it could be argued, should be imputed to the state where the storage happens assuming there are no additional costs.

It isn't uncommon for firms and people to split the location of capital, expense and revenue among various states.  You could have servers in one state, programmers in another state working from home selling to a customer in a third state.

Each state makes its own laws as to how to allocate the role of capital, expenses and revenue.  They often conflict.  You end up having to follow all the laws, which can result in higher taxes overall.

Once you enter a state, you become subject to its laws.  Because we live in a virtual world, the states require a "nexus," into the state. You do not have to step foot in it.

Each state is sovereign, subject to the federal powers granted to the national government in the Constitution.  They are free to do anything they want as long as it doesn't specifically conflict with a federal power, or a right granted by the Constitution.  They were intended to be a federated set of sovereign nations, the meaning of "state" at the time.  They can do most anything they like inside their borders, particularly with regards to taxation.

I used to live in a place that had a tax on breathing. If you were breathing, it was $7.50 per year.  You didn't have to pay it if you stopped breathing during the year.  They were not going to dig you up to get you to pay.

I also lived in a state where towns could charge a tax on a business's worldwide income. It actually could be a material amount for a multinational corporation.  Step foot in one of those towns for one second during the year and you could owe enormous sums.

Comment: playing nice has nothing to do with constitutional, the answer would be based on citing a court challenge or lack thereof. in this case, the differences in treatment could fail a 5th amendment or 14th amendment if the state fails to prove its case well.

Comment: I'm swayed now that this question is off topic for this venue, but I also think this is a pretty good answer.  It makes me wonder just how aggressive a state could be.  If I drive from Detroit to Miami and pay tolls in every state along the way, could every one of them declare that I owe tax on all my worldwide income?  Could states and cities, without any true malevolence or conspiracy but simply greed, all tax me at a combined rate that far exceeds my actual income?  I need to figure out how to pose these questions constructively, probably in Law SE.